# my cron job not working well in laravel it work only once

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron

i am working on laravel crone job it work only one time my code execute only one time i am a beginer

```php
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
  {
      $schedule->command('list:users')->everyMinute();
  }
```

```php
class ListUsers extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'list:users';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'corn job command';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $totalUsers = \DB::table('users')->whereMonth('created_at','04')->count();
        Mail::to('qasim@gmail.com')->send(new SendMailable($totalUsers));
    }
```

I am also try this code

```php
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
     $schedule->call(function () {
            echo "pakistan\n";
            $totalUsers = \DB::table('users')->whereMonth('created_at','04')->count();
            Mail::to('qasim@gmail.com')->send(new SendMailable($totalUsers));
            echo "pakistan";
        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

i want user recieve email after every minute
i recieve mail once but not every minute

Comment: Did you add the Laravel cron-entry to the server? 

* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: no but i dont know where to add and which code to add i am beginer so kindly send me command as well as path

Comment: i am working on localhost